# What is the preferred way to give asymmetric uncertainties?

Tags: uncertainty, notation

I have seen something like

$4.1^{+2.1}_{-1.5}$

or

$4.1 [+2.1, -1.5]$

but I would like to know, what is the preferred way or something like a standard in scientific work (especially in physics/engineering)?

Comment: One standard format is "95% CI [5.62, 8.31]": http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/06/formatting-statistics-using-brackets.html.  A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=confidence+interval+exposition+reporting) turned this up and undoubtedly will turn up additional standards if you pursue it.

Comment: @whuber that's what the only answer up to now also suggests. However it is mentioned that it is related to social sciences.

Comment: If I had this question I would consult (a) any editorial guidance for the journal in which I wished to publish this stuff and then, if that were not clear, I would (b) look at recent papers in the journal. Those are the authoritative sources of such information; anything else--no matter how well reasoned or supported--will not matter; you have to follow the journal's policy.

Comment: @whuber I think this is a good advice, but thats my problem: in the journal I want to publish my paper there is no guide for this kind of questions and I don't know an article in this journal, where asymmetric uncertainties are given (it's something like engineering, not statistics).

Comment: In experimental physics journals $4.1^{+2.1}_{-1.5}$ is certainly a very common way of expressing asymmetric measurement errors, but I can't find an example at the moment...

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your paper only reports one or a few such values, there is nothing wrong with being wordy so no one can get confused:

> "The mean is 4.1 and the 95% confidence interval ranges from 2.6 to 6.2."

(Of course, replace "mean" with "slope" or whatever parameter you are actually reporting.)

Answer (score 3):

It would depend on the field and the journal. In the social sciences, it would be mean = 4.1, 95% CI = ???

I like specifying that it's a CI, because the +- notation could be standard deviation, standard errors, or who knows what.

Comment: So for my example this would be `4.1, 95% CI = [+2.1, -1.5]`?

Comment: Yes, although usually it's written with the smaller number first: mean = 41, 95% CI = -1.5 to 2.1.

Comment: I think rather in this example it would most typically be mean = 4.1 CI = 2.6 to 6.2.  I.e. the confidence interval is usual expressed as total amounts rather than differences from the mean (at least that's what I've seen)

Comment: Yes, @Corone is right

Answer (score 3):

Astrophysics commonly use $4.1^{+2.1}_{-1.5}$ style, for example :

http://iopscience.iop.org/0004-637X/765/1/47

Also see wikipedia using the same style:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R136a1